# Zend Framework support for DynamoDB

Tags: php, zend-framework, amazon-dynamodb

I'm looking at amazon's DynamoDB service to store logs from our application (specifically using `Zend_Log` writers) into a DynamoDB database.

Right now, there's no native support for DynamoDB in zend framework, and looks like amazon changed their signature handling to a newer version ( http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/general/latest/gr/signing_aws_api_requests.html ), which means that zend framework can't even sign API requests for amazon's new services.

Anyone is familiar with Zend_Log_Writer that can work with DynamoDB service? or has some pointers on implementing such a writer?

I'm also considering their session management handler using `Zend_Session` ( http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=AmazonDynamoDB/register_session_handler ). But, again, there's no native support in zend framework for it.

Answer (score 1):

If Zend Framework doesn't support DynamoDB, then you will need to create a custom adapter that extends `Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract` and implements all of the methods appropriately for DynamoDB. Once that is completed, you can use it just like any other Zend_Db object in your application.

Then you can [create a custom log writer](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.log.writers.html) by extending the `Zend_Log_Writer_Abstract` class and implementing the abstract methods to use your DynamoDB adapter for writing the data.

Comment: I would suggest you create a custom adapter that extends Zend_Service_Amazon_AbstractAmazon. Just follow the example of Zend_Service_Amazon_SimpleDb.

Comment: @chameleon95 thanks. that's exactly what I did. I also published it as a component, if anyone else is interested https://github.com/aporat/Zend_Log_Writer_DynamoDb

Comment: Great job sharing it with the world :)

Comment: Just a note - you should use your own prefix for your classes - not generic "application" and also not "zend" when it's not part of ZF. (but i made that mistake too with zend form bootstrap)